# SB_GETTEXT filling stringbuilder with nothing

Tags: c#, winapi, stringbuilder

I'm trying to get the text from a part of statusbar on another application. I can get the handles OK, I just can't get the text from my stringbuilder, when shown in a message box, it shows nothing.

Code so far

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int message, int wParam,           [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int message, int wParam, int lParam);

IntPtr statbarhandle = IntPtr.Zero;
StringBuilder sbb = new StringBuilder(50);
StringBuilder classname = new StringBuilder(20);
classname.Append("msctls_statusbar32");
statbarhandle = FindWindowEx(gr3hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, classname, null);
int numofparts = SendMessage(statbarhandle, 0x406, 0, 0); 
SendMessage(statbarhandle, 0x402, 3, sbb);
MessageBox.Show(sbb.ToString());
```

SB_GETPARTS works perfectly by the way.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you're not passing `SB_GETTEXT`.

In the header files, `SB_GETTEXT` is defined as `(WM_USER+13)`, and `WM_USER` is defined as `0x0400`. So you should be passing `0x040d` in your `SendMessage`. You're passing `0x0402`, which is `TB_CHECKBUTTON`.

See the constant definitions at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SB_GETTEXT.html.

It's a little more complicated than that. I see now that `SB_GETTEXTA` (the ANSI version) is 0x0402. `SB_GETTEXTW` is `0x040d`. You want `SB_GETTEXTW`.

Comment: I don't think that's it. The code is sending the ANSI message and marshaling as ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the system does not, for this `WM_USER` message, perform cross-process marshaling of text. The pointer you pass is a pointer to memory in your process. But the control interprets it as a pointer to memory in its address space. Which it is not.

You could deal with this by using VirtualAlloc, ReadProcessMemory etc. to allocate and then read memory in the target process. A better approach would be to use UIAutomation to read this information.